# How to pass an array in Magento 2 custom rest api?

Tags: rest, api, magento2

Magento 2 custom rest api,I can not get an array in modalrepository,

How can i pass an array as parameter ?

**Webapi.xml**

```
    <route method="POST" url="/V1/topmarkens/productlists">
        <service class="Meridian\TopMarken\Api\TopMarkenRepositoryInterface" 
           method="productFilterByBrand"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="types" force="true">%types%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>
```

**TopMarkenRepositoryInterface.php**

```
    /**
     * return placed order status
     * @param string[] $types
     * @return \Meridian\TopMarken\Api\Data\TopMarkenInterface
     */
    public function productFilterByBrand($types);
```

**TopMarkenRepository.php**

```
   public function productFilterByBrand($types){
        $vendor_data = json_decode($types);

        echo "<pre>"; print_r($vendor_data); die;

        return $vendor_data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly sending an array as a parameter is not a good way of doing a POST request. I suggest you to send a json object in which u can have array as an first element of your object.

Answer (score 0):

I have this json:

```
{
   "customerEmail":"myFancyEmail@gmail.com",
    "items": [
        {"sku":"sku-1", "qty":"1"},
        {"sku":"sku-2", "qty":"2"}
    ]
}
```

and this is my interface:

```
interface OrderInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $customerEmail
     * @param mixed $items
     * @return bool
     * @api
     */
    public function create(string $customerEmail, $items) : bool;
}
```

Using `string[]` or `array` or `mixed[]` didn't work out for me. Only `mixed`